# Can an uninitialized automatic volatile variable in C be safely read?

Tags: c, volatile, undefined-behavior

In C, can I access an automatic volatile variable without having to initialize it first, or does it always result in undefined behavior?

E.g., in some hardware devices mapped to volatile variables, initializing the variable makes no sense anyway, or might even be forbidden.

Comment: *How* are the variables declared? Is it using some compiler-extension for the mapping? Or are you using pointers?

Comment: If hardware registers are mapped to variables, then I doubt very much that those variables would have automatic storage duration. As such this question doesn't make sense. Please give an example code of what you mean.

Comment: A `volatile` variable mapped to a hardware device wouldn't be `automatic`.

Comment: Why would you not be able to read it?  It doesn't have to be UB.

Comment: @MartinJames Because it is an uninitialized variable with indeterminate value. Using variables with indeterminate value will cause undefined behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An automatic variable is generally on the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (but this is implementation specific), so it generally won't be some hardware specific "device" (unless your stack pointer is garbage). When that is the case (to be on stack), a variable inherits from the previous content of that stack location. If it is volatile e.g, like in

```
void foo(void) {
  volatile int x;
  // here x contains garbage
}
```

accessing that `x` gives some "indeterminate value", and that access is an undefined behavior.

<sup>The C standard does not require any call stack, but most C implementations use the machine call stack.</sup>

Of course, things are different if you have an automatic variable which is a pointer to some volatile data.

Comment: Often hardware registers are represented as pointers to `volatile`, and those *pointers* can of course be automatic. Perhaps this is confusing the OP.

Comment: @unwind Declaring a pointer like for example `volatile int* ptr;` doesn't make the _pointer variable_ volatile though. It is still a plain automatic storage variable (given that it was declared at local scope). In order to make the actual pointer volatile, you'd have to write something obscure such as `int* volatile ptr;`. Why anyone would want to do that for, I have no idea.

Comment: @Lundin Uh, yes, that's exactly what I said ... or at least what I wanted to say. The pointer can be automatic while pointing at volatile data, but that doesn't make the thing that is automatic also be the thing that is volatile.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the value of an uninitialized variable (or memory location) will result in undefined behaviour with regard to the C standard. That means that the C standard doesn't say what will happen.

There are other sources that may define what will happen in certain cases. In the case of volatile variables, the definition of what happens is almost always platform dependent.

So you need to consult the relevant documentation for the variable in question.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is a hardware memory mapped I/O location, use volatile, not atomic, and clearly it should only be initialized based if the hardware needs it to be initialized.

The C++ 11 standard states that volatile should not be used for non-hardware memory mapped I/O. Use atomic or one of the synchronization types (event, mutex, semaphore, ...) to provide a [Memory Barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) as needed.

Microsoft and possibly some other compilers have vendor specific extensions that provide memory barriers with volatile variables (as a command line option in VS2012 and later versions, always enabled on older versions), but this is non-standard usage.